# T-SQL select string where on fourth position is any number except 9

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to select mobile phone numbers that are beginning with +385 and on next position could be any number except 9. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are lucky, I was looking for an occasion to spin up my lubuntu SQL server VM , check this testing code should answer the question

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Alex](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO



insert into Alex (Phone) values ('+3329855870421');
insert into Alex (Phone) values ('+3850125611333');
insert into Alex (Phone) values ('+3859125611333');

GO

select * from Alex where Phone like '+385[0-8]%'
```

Comment: I didn't know about that square bracket piece of syntax - was going to suggest a LIKE x AND NOT LIKE y approach before yours loaded in

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful, can you please suggest the condition for cases when I want to select all numbers except 2 on this position

Comment: select * from Alex where Phone like '+385[0-1|3-9]%' will return rows that after +385 have any of 0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9